# How do I unstack these three histogram columns? Position Argument Fails

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I am using the below code to create a histogram plot of three different variables. I would like to separate out the three bars at each data point in order to obtain a better visualizations. I tried adding the "position" argument for each feature but it won't work

```
count, bin_edges = np.histogram(df['age'])

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,3))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111) # Create matplotlib axes

df['age'].plot(kind = 'hist', figsize=(10,5), xticks = bin_edges, 
               width = 2, color = 'blue', alpha=0.4)

df[df['y'] == 1]['age'].plot(kind = 'hist', figsize=(10,5), xticks = bin_edges, 
               width = 2, color='red', alpha=0.4)

df[(df['y'] == 1)&(df['new_customer'] == 1)]['age'].plot(kind = 'hist', figsize=(10,5), xticks = bin_edges, 
               width = 2, color='green', alpha=0.4)

plt.title("Age")
plt.xlabel("Age Bins")
plt.ylabel("Number of Contacts")
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

EDIT: this is what my df looks like:

```
df[['age', 'y', 'new_customer']]


   age  y   new_customer
0   56  0   1
1   57  0   1
2   37  0   1
3   40  0   1
4   56  0   1
5   45  0   1
6   59  0   1
7   41  0   1
8   24  0   1
9   25  0   1
10  41  0   1
11  25  0   1
12  29  0   1
```

[image: This is what the image looks like now. I would like to have three separate columns at each age bin cutoff rather than a single stacked column]

Comment: Add a short representative example of your `df`.  It only needs to have the 3 columns used in the code (`'age'`, `'y'` and `'new_customer'`), and it should probably have 3 or 4 rows so the output plot looks sensible.

Comment: Sorry about that, I added df, I hope it looks realistic enough

Comment: An image of the actual and desired results would be very helpful. Could you post that please?

Comment: Sorry, I just added the image. Basically, I would just like to obtain three columns where now I have a single, stacked column

Comment: Your columns aren't actually stacked. They're just overlapping. Really what your code does is it just makes 3 overlapping histogram plots.

Comment: You're right about that! Sorry it's so late... Anyways I had tried to use the "position" argument in a similar example, and for some reason it is not working in this case.

Comment: I think `position` only works for bar plots in Pandas, not histograms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pandas plotting api isn't nearly as flexible as the underlying Matplotlib library it uses to make the actual plots. Just use Matplotlib directly:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

csv = '''   age  y   new_customer
0   56  0   1
1   57  1   1
2   37  0   1
3   40  0   1
4   56  1   1
5   45  0   0
6   59  0   1
7   41  1   1
8   24  0   0
9   25  0   1
10  41  1   1
11  25  0   0
12  29  0   1'''

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(csv), sep='\s+')

bin_edges = np.histogram_bin_edges(df['age'])

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,3))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111) # Create matplotlib axes

data = [df['age'], 
        df[df['y'] == 1]['age'],
        df[(df['y'] == 1)&(df['new_customer'] == 1)]['age']]
plt.hist(data, bins=bin_edges, label=['age', 'age_y', 'age_y_newcustomer'])

bin_cens = (bin_edges[:-1] + bin_edges[1:])/2
plt.xticks(bin_cens)

plt.title("Age")
plt.xlabel("Age Bins (center)")
plt.ylabel("Number of Contacts")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I had tried that as well and I just couldn't get this to have centered columns. In other words, the columns are not centered around the tickmarks; would you be able to correct your answer to reflect this?

Comment: Let me make sure I understand: in my above example output, you would want the center of the orange bars to be at the center of each histogram bin, right?

Comment: The bar alignment you want is, in fact, already the default behavior of `plt.hist`. I updated my answer so that the bin centers are explicitly marked on the x-axis, to make this clearer.

Comment: Ah! I just noticed the problem was not the centering but it was the labels for the xticks all along!! So sorry for the inconvenience but thank you so much for the help. I learned a lot from your plot in addition to what I was asking for!